# Fedora "disk full", df, du (gui) confirm but gparted shows the partition is big enough

Tags: disk-usage, gparted, df

I am running a fedora Virtual machine and after much pain I managed to extend my virtual machines .vdi, from 20gb to 40gb. However it appears my pain is not over.

The machine still complains of low disk space, still has many errors and the gui disk usage analyzer shows I am full and so does df. However gparted tells me I have 40gb on that partition.

is it Virtual box weirdness? do i need to kick fedora in some way to refresh its known capacity?

Please find attached a screen grab of all the relevant applications, let me know if you need more info. Thank you

[image: Sceengrab of info]

Comment: Please don't crosspost. Instead, flag a mod to move it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filesystem is 20G on a partition that has 40G. You need to resize the filesystem! *growfs* is the correct tool.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I am currently looking for growfs on fedora, so far no luck, will report in once I find it/equivalent

Comment: Ok so i believe resize2fs is the equivalent? here are my results:
`sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_chris-lv_root 39G
"resize2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
The containing partition (or device) is only 4792320 (4k) blocks.
You requested a new size of 10223616 blocks.

sudo resize2fs /dev/sda3 39G
"resize2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/sda3
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock."`

Answer (score 1):

Ok Massive thanks to neutrinus for pointing me in the right direction and for this post:

http://allaboutfedora.blogspot.de/2007/01/how-to-resize-or-expand-lvm-partitions.html

I did:

- init 3
- sudo lvextend -L+19GB /dev/mapper/vg_chris-lv_root
- sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_chris-lv_root

where -L means "size" and +19GB adds 19GB, running resize2fs without arguments seems to automatically fill the space